# C++ Tree View Controls, Get Full path of selected item

Tags: c++, windows, treeview, atl, treeviewitem

Currently I have a tree view control and I'm handling the `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` command which is fine, however I can't seem to find a way to get an absolute path from the tree view control. *i.e*

```
- C:\\
  - Documents
    - Test.txt
```

Lets say I double click Documents I would like to get the full path which would be

> 'C:\Documents'

and if I double clicked on `Test.txt` I would like to get the full path which would be

> 'C:\Documents\Test.txt'

Is this possible?

Comment: You can always compose full path yourself walking up with `TVGN_PARENT` up the tree and adding up text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "corresponding" .net control has a property called [FullPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.fullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can take a look at the c# implementation at [TreeNode.cs@GetFullPath()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNode.cs,43eed904c509b437,references). You can (and have to) do pretty much the same in your code as well. (it doesn't *have to* be recursion, but it *can* be ;-))